# Why does usermod default to overwriting secondary groups?

Tags: group, history, usermod

As anyone who has used `usermod` to add a user to a group knows, invariably a mistake will be made (probably once in a career and not again) in which `-a` is forgotten and the secondary groups are overwritten with `uucp` or some other group with low permissions, locking the user out.

What is the historical reason for the default for usermod being to exhibit the behaviour that few people want of overwriting the secondary groups?

Comment: I guess it's because it doesn't have a good way to otherwise *remove* secondary groups... So `-a` works to add new, but if you want to remove or replace then you need to specify them all...

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger Perhaps, but why does replacing the groups *not* require a flag?

Comment: usermod command can use to add user to secondary group.

Comment: @ErandaPeiris I am aware. I'm asking about the historical reason for it overwriting secondary groups by default instead of requiring a flag to do so.

Comment: https://man.openbsd.org/usermod : -G and -S, no -a. "past": http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man1/usermod.1m.html : -G and nothing.